# Lottery and expectation

Tags: probability

At the lottery, you have a one in 250 million chance to win 240 million dollars. Let X be the amount you win. Calculate $E(X)$ and $Var(X)$.

So intuitively, I was thinking it would be $E(X)=240,000,000/250,000,000 $ , but I am a little confused about variance here.

What distribution is this?

Comment: Are there any other prizes, or just the grand prize? If the latter, your intuition is spot on. Otherwise, it's not. As for the variance, how is it defined for you?

Comment: Just the grand prize. I mean I generally remember the variance formula: $E(X^2)-(E(X))^2 $ but would this apply here?

Comment: would it be then for Var(X)=240,000,000^2/250,000,000 - (240,000,000/250,000,000)^2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem, based on the information given, that $X$ takes on the value $\$240$ million with probability $1/250000000,$ and otherwise takes on a value of $\$0.$ Can you take it from there?

Comment: do you mean this for variance or expectation?

Comment: I mean this for both.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, *if this is for just one ticket and the winnings are all or nothing*, then:

$$E(X) = 240\,000\,000\cdot\dfrac{1}{250\,000\,000} + 0\cdot\dfrac{249\,999\,999}{250\,000\,000}$$

Clearly then: $$E(X^2) = 240\,000\,000^2\cdot\dfrac{1}{250\,000\,000} + 0^2\cdot\dfrac{249\,999\,999}{250\,000\,000}$$

And as $\mathsf {Var}(X) = \mathsf E(X^2)-\mathsf E(X)^2$ you have enough to proceed.